# Сколько объектов будут недоступны, и поэтому могут быть удалены, если сборщик мусора запустится сразу после выполнения следующего кода:

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Ситуацию МОЖНО воспроизвести: достаточно просто воспроизвести следующий код. И вопрос задан по существу и касается механизма работы сборщика мусора.

Если сборщик мусора запустится сразу после выполнения `m1 = null;` `m2 = null;`, то сколько объектов будет недоступны, и поэтому могут быть удалены сборщиком мусора?

```
public class MyTest {
    MyTest m;

    void show() {
        System.out.println("Привет, Мир.");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyTest m1 = new MyTest();
        MyTest m2 = new MyTest();
        MyTest m3 = new MyTest();
        m1.m = m2;
        m2.m = m3;
        m3.m = m1;
        m1 = null;
        m2 = null;
        // Вопрос: если сборщик мусора запустится здесь, то сколько объектов будет недоступны, и поэтому могут быть удалены сборщиком мусора?
    }
}
```

Comment: Ни одного, потому что останутся ссылки и на m1 и на m2. Вы могли бы просто проверить это: `System.out.print( m3.m.m )`

Comment: @ReinRaus, запилите лучше ответ )

Comment: Корректного ответа нету: сборщик мусора вовсе не **обязан** реально удалять недоступные объекты.

Comment: @VladD я и имел в виду то, сколько объектов будут недоступны, и потому *могут* быть удалены сборщиком мусора

Comment: Ни один объект он *не сможет* в этой точке удалить, как уже указал @ReinRaus.

Comment: @avp ну вот после моего уточнения формулировки вопроса можно и дать ответ, а не комментарий

Comment: @ReinRaus Когда вы пишите `System.out.print(m3.m.m)`, вы делаете явную ссылку на `m3`, а, значит, транзитивно и на `m1` с `m2`. Но без этой строчки нет ни одного strong reference на `m3`, и поэтому все три объекта могут быть собраны. См. [мой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460765/189733).

Comment: @apangin спасибо. А если не будет JIT-компиляции, то JVM не сделает вывод, что m3 можно освободить?

Comment: @ReinRaus Интерпретатор исполняет байткод в первозданном виде. В этом случае переменные в области своей видимости размещаются на стеке, т.е. на стеке будет переменная m3 с живой ссылкой на объект. Стало быть, объект достижим и не соберётся. В скомпилированном же коде переменная не обязана где-либо размещаться, если ниже по коду она не используется.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Вы удивитесь, но правильный ответ - **Implementation defined**.

В том смысле, что в зависимости от реализации JVM могут быть освобождены хоть все объекты MyTest, хоть ни одного. И в обоих случаях поведение будет абсолютно корректным по отношению к [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6) и [Java Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.2).

Докажу на примере:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    MyTest m1 = new MyTest();
    MyTest m2 = new MyTest();
    MyTest m3 = new MyTest();
    m1.m = m2;
    m2.m = m3;
    m3.m = m1;
    m1 = null;
    m2 = null;

    // Слабая ссылка обнулится, как только объект m3 будет собран
    WeakReference<?> ref = new WeakReference<>(m3);
    for (int i = 0; ref.get() != null; i++) {
        if ((i % 1000) == 0) System.gc();
    }

    System.out.println("m3 is garbage-collected");
}
```

После нескольких тысяч итераций цикла метод скомпилируется JITом, ссылок на объект `m3` больше не будет, и он удалится после очередной сборки мусора. Однако если запустить Java с флагом `-Xint`, то ссылка на m3 всегда будет лежать доступной на стеке, и программа зациклится.

Забавно, но факт: даже объект `this` может быть освобождён сборщиком мусора прямо во время выполнения метода на этом объекте. Подробности в [JDK-8055183](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8055183).

В Java 9 даже будут [дополнения](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046178) к Java Memory Model и специальный метод [Reference.reachabilityFence](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/193), чтобы избежать подобных курьёзов.

Comment: Cпасибо! Чуть попозже разберусь со всем этим :)